# Clojure + Swing absolute positioning problems

Tags: swing, clojure

I'm writing a small app where I want absolute positioning - I can get what I want with seemingly an ugly workaround, however I would like to know how I can make this code cleaner maintaining the same functionality.

The problem is if I omit either (.setBounds ..) s-exprs then the JPanel fills the entire JFrame. Thanks in advance, here is working sample code:

```
...
(:import [javax.swing JFrame JPanel]
         [javax.swing.border LineBorder]
         [java.awt Color])

(defn frame []
  (let [top-panel (doto (JPanel.)
                     (.setOpaque true) 
                     (.setVisible true)
                     (.setBounds 25 25 250 75)
                     (.setBorder (LineBorder. (Color. 255 0 0 255))))

        frame (doto (JFrame.)
                 (.setLayout nil)
                 (.setResizable false)
                 (.setSize 300 625)
                 (.setVisible true)
                 (.setContentPane top-panel))]

     (.setBounds top-panel 25 25 250 75)))
```

Comment: Is there a typo in the listing? You are defining a function named "frame" and a local within the let called "frame" as well. Was that your intention?

Comment: @clartaq I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: @amalloy: Yup, nothing wrong with it. Just wondered if there was any confusion about the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code gives me the functionality I was looking for, replacing .contentPane with .add

```
(defn frame []
  (let [top-panel (doto (JPanel.)
                     (.setBounds 25 25 250 75)
                     (.setVisible true)
                     (.setBorder (LineBorder. (Color. 255 0 0 255))))]

        (doto (JFrame.)
           (.setLayout nil)
           (.setSize 300 625)
           (.setVisible true)
           (.add top-panel)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I could not get your code to work. When I made mods to get it to run I got the panel tightly wrapped by the frame.

I'm assuming you want the top-panel in the middle of the larger frame with empty space on all sides. The usual way to do this would be to create a main panel with the size of the frame you want. Then, using a layout manager like BorderLayout, add additional JPanels to the main panel. The top-panel would be given the dimensions you want and surrounding panels would provide the "padding". If the surrounding panels are created with empty borders, it should look like the top-panel is surrounded by empty area.

**EDIT**:

Here's something that may be a bit closer to your intention. The BorderLayout probably does not give the panel sizing priority you want. Maybe GridBagLayout?

```
(ns com.so.abspos
 (:import (javax.swing JFrame JPanel)
      (java.awt BorderLayout))
 (:gen-class true))

(defn frame []
  (let [
    center-panel (doto (JPanel.)
      (.setOpaque true) 
      (.setVisible true)
      (.setSize 225 50)
      ;(.setBounds 25 25 250 75)
      (.setBorder (javax.swing.border.LineBorder. (java.awt.Color. 255 0 0 255))))

    top-panel (doto (JPanel.)
      (.setSize 625 25))

    left-panel (doto (JPanel.)
      (.setSize 25 75))

    bottom-panel (doto (JPanel.)
      (.setSize 625 300))

    right-panel (doto (JPanel.)
      (.setSize 250 75))

    main-panel (doto (JPanel.)
      (.setLayout (new BorderLayout))
      (.add left-panel BorderLayout/WEST)
      (.add top-panel BorderLayout/NORTH)
      (.add center-panel BorderLayout/CENTER)
      (.add right-panel BorderLayout/EAST)
      (.add bottom-panel BorderLayout/SOUTH))

    aframe (doto (JFrame.)
      (.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
      (.setResizable false)
      (.setSize 300 625)
      (.setVisible true)
      (.setContentPane main-panel))]))

(defn -main
  "Just create the frame and show it."
  []
  (frame))
```

Comment: thanks for the effort put into this, i started reading a book on swing, I think the problem was messing with .contentPane when I should have been using .add, I'll post the code below